# Dynamically place nodes in cytoscape.js based on values, avoiding overlaps

Tags: javascript, layout, graph, cytoscape.js

[image]I am generating 1st level graph from dynamic values. When any node is clicked, it creates new nodes and place them based on the priority (max. value will be closer to clicked node). How can I place them without overlapping?

Comment: what's a "1st level graph"?

Comment: "1st level graph" is the first nodes from the center. I am using cose layout. I edited the question i think it will solve the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Place nodes manually using [`node.position()`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#node.position), noting [bounding boxes](http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.boundingBox) to fix overlap.

or

(2) Use one of the [layouts](http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts) on a [subset of the graph](http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.layout) (i.e. the nodes of interest).